# http.get don't make a call, Angular 2

Tags: http, get, angular

I am playing with angular 2 and I have problem with sending http get request.
I created method like this:

```
  test(){
     console.log("call test");
     let header =  new Headers();
     header.append("authorization",'change9ziKuJH8wnVbNES3AMleYGPKzZ');

     this._http.get('http://localhost:42055/api/Question',{headers:header}).do(res => console.log("Result: " + JSON.stringify(res)));
```

}

The main problem is that, this http request never was send. I look at the Fiddler and there is no request to my localhost:42055.

Unfortunately Angular don't display any errors, so I don't have any clue what is going one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observables are lazy so you need to subscribe them to actually execute corresponding processing (HTTP requests in your case):

```
this._http.get('http://localhost:42055/api/Question',{headers:header})
   .do(res => console.log("Result: " + JSON.stringify(res)))
   .subscribe((res) => { // <-------------
     // handle result
   });
```